# Get Visio 2016 to snap to grid only

Tags: visio

I am running into an issue in Visio 2016.

I am trying to get the connecter routing to only snap to my set grid size (to keep everything aligned and neat looking). However, if i have boxes, images, or shapes in the diagram, it always seems to want to snap to the center of the image/box.

I have turned off glue, and have tried turning off all snap options except "Snap to grid", however, even with that setting, it still snaps to the center of the image/box.

How do i force visio to stay to the grid snap, without disabling it entirely?

Comment: Your shape has a connection point in the center of the image/box. By design, connectors will snap to connection points. You can delete all the connection points.

Comment: Not sure if it is a V2016 issue, but at least still V2013 you have an option to increase the snapping "force" of elements like grid, geometry, etc. Check this link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/adjust-snap-strength-or-turn-snap-off-94dadb54-f6b1-45f5-9795-c3ec2a1f8671

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem after I switched from Visio 2010 to Visio 2013. The only way I could achieve desired behavior of dynamic connector (not to auto glue to center of shape) is to change "GlueType" cell value to 4 in "Glue Info" Shapesheet section of connector - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff769196.aspx. Connector will still glue to connections points if any.
To enable ShapeSheet menu: File->Options->Customize Ribbon and check Developer tab.